# Selective Mandatory fields in a jsp

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a query for jsp.

Scenario: Suppose I have two fields

Field One: Connection Type (selective dropdown)
Dropdown options:
1. GSM
2. CDMA
3. Others

Field two: Comments (Free Text)

Question:
How do I make it mandatory for user to enter the 'comments' free text box only if the 'Connection Type' was selected as 'Others'

Comment: If "Others" was selected, then check that the comments is not empty. Otherwise, don't. What's the concrete problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially disable the text area and when onchanging the dropdown, get the selected value. If it's not empty, enable the text box. In HTML

```
<select id="connectionType" name="connectionType" onchange="changeText()">
    <option value="">Select a value</option>
    <option value="gsm">GSM</option>
   <option value="cdma">CDMA</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="comments" disabled="true" />
```

And in javascript,

```
function changeText() {
    if(document.getElementById("connectionType").value !=""){
        //alert(document.getElementById("connectionType").value);
       document.getElementById("comments").disabled=false;   
    }else{
        document.getElementById("comments").disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.The demo in **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vSHQD/104/)** is here